# Linked italic text is not highlighted on the mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, mobile-web

When italics are applied within a link tag, `em { color: black; }` overrides `a { color: #938322; }`, with the result that the link is indistinguishable from other italic text on the mobile site:

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot demonstrating what I'm talking about]

#### Demo

*Italic text*
**Bold text**

[A link](http://s.tk/)
[*Linked italic text*](http://s.tk/)
[**Linked bold text**](http://s.tk/)

*[An italicized link](http://s.tk/)*
**[A boldfaced link](http://s.tk/)**

#### Source

```
*Italic text*  
**Bold text**

[A link](http://s.tk/)  
[*Linked italic text*](http://s.tk/)  
[**Linked bold text**](http://s.tk/)

*[An italicized link](http://s.tk/)*  
**[A boldfaced link](http://s.tk/)**
```

To anyone else who's wondering: the default font color is `#222`. Italic text is apparently  darkened to help compensate for its lighter weight.

Comment: I also see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this and it will be out in `rev 2226` (meta) and `rev 1592` (network).